# in cakephp4 how to access a model within a model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-4.x

How do i access another model within a model in cakephp4.2? The docs on this issue isnt clear to me and i can then run a query on this ? TableRegistry is deprecated now.

```
 error Unknown method "getTableLocator" called on App\Model\Table\LessonsTable  

//none of these no longer work
in model {

use Cake\ORM\Locator\LocatorAwareTrait;


class LessonsTable extends Table
 {
 ..

  private function  getlessonRevenue(){

  //$clients = $this->getTableLocator()->get('Clients');
  // $cleints = TableRegistry::get('Clients'); 
  // $this->Table = TableRegistry::get('Clients');
   $clients = $this->getTableLocator()->get('Clients');
```

https://api.cakephp.org/4.0/class-Cake.ORM.TableRegistry.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
use Cake\ORM\Locator\LocatorAwareTrait; //<------------ add here
class ArchivesTable extends Table
{
  use LocatorAwareTrait; // <--------------------------- and add here
  public function myMethod()
  {
      $clients = $this->getTableLocator()->get('Clients');
  }
```

and read **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/table-objects.html#using-the-tablelocator**

and learn how to use php trait https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-traits/

Comment: Unknown method "getTableLocator" called on App\Model\Table

Comment: I go this error with the command  use Cake\ORM\Locator\LocatorAwareTrait;       Unknown method "getTableLocator" called on App\Model\Table   as i already said so above i used this command.

Comment: did you load trait? use \Cake\ORM\Locator\LocatorAwareTrait; ?

Comment: i added more code above to make it clearer and i have no idea why it hasnt worked

Comment: it works when i add use LocatorAwareTrait;  outside the function. This is a very complicated way to just get a model compared to earlier versions of cakephp? you just had to do this before  $articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');

Comment: Since 4.3.0, you can also use `fetchTable` method. See: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm.html#quick-example